# How do I remove these dark spots?

Tags: jquery, html, css

They used to be numbers, but I changed to background color to hide them.

[image: http://gyazo.com/5211ecfcb8eedeb1332bbfe23180a366]

[image: http://gyazo.com/3257fc8f8b72502dfa251d0f0115a6c3]

[image]

These numbers tell you how many links are in each submenu and I don't want that.

I looked over the code and there's literally nothing that's causing this I even removed the jQuery and it still stayed.

Comment: I then tried changing the opacity of the background, but then even more numbers show!

Comment: http://gyazo.com/4539d2e88bf4f75401cf64348480621c

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7EgkY/

Comment: styling starts at line 404

Comment: Consider using the "edit" button below your question to add more data. That's a more proper and visible place than the comments.

Comment: I was only allowed to have 2 links.

Comment: Your fiddle seems to render correctly in my Chrome and Firefox. By the way, in the future try to make simpler fiddles with just enough code to reproduce the issue (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for guidance).

Comment: I know. I said I changed the opacity which caused it to add more numbers. So I changed it back. What Im trying to do is remove the the dark spots that are to the right of of MEN,  and WOMEN. Which is shown in the images above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a span with a black background color sitting there.  Not sure if you need it or not.

```
<a href="#">
    <span>MEN</span>
    <span class="cnt">0</span>
</a>
```

I'm referring to the span with the "cnt" class.  Consider removing it or editing the CSS so that it doesn't show.

```
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
    background: #000000; /* Delete this?  */
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```